# Which of the following is a degree-100 extension of $\Bbb Q(i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Which of the following is a degree-100 extension of $\Bbb Q(i)$?

1. $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle{x^{200}+1}\rangle$.
2. $\Bbb Q (\sqrt[100]{i-3})$

For the first one, I am not sure how to prove $x^{200}+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: It's not irreducible -- it's a sum of two 5th powers.

Comment: $i-3$ is a product of two non-associate primes of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, so you can apply EIsenstein.

Comment: @quasi I think the notion of "irreduicibility" is related to the product. Not the sum. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @ymxu0809 I think quasi's point is that an expression $a^5+b^5$ can be factorised.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what are the two primes? What elements in $\Bbb Z[i]$ are prime?

Comment: ymxu0809 Are you familiar with the norm map $N:\Bbb{Z}[i]\to\Bbb{Z}, a+bi\mapsto a^2+b^2$? It is easy to prove that $a+bi$ is a prime is $N(a+bi)$ is a prime (more can be said, but this is enough here). Anyway, play with $1+i$, $2\pm i$ and unit multipliers (= powers of $i$).